# Confusion in Regular expression in SpringBoot

Tags: java, regex

Yesterday I was going through a question that goes like:

> Write the regexp for "Id can have  words containing alphabets and numbers, and each word should be separated by a single space"
> I wrote

```
[A-Za-z0-9/s]
```

Now, when thinking about it, can the answer be

```
[A-Za-z0-9 ]//{1}
```

or was I right?

Comment: This is not a Spring Boot question, you should probably tag this with 'regex' and maybe the language you are working in. I like Java, so this is mine: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`

Comment: @OP your regex (both) will accept space alone as an input.